# Getting same result from function every time

Tags: javascript, html

why is my function returning the same result?

I would like to input all the values from the “ping” function to an array and then output that array in html.
I run the function 3 times but all three times the result is the same. Can you tell me why?

(The domains are just an example by the way, cant put originals here)

```
  var str = ' ';
  var t=[];
  var n= 2;
  var arr = ["www.google.com","www.example.com","www.example2.com"];
  var results = [];
  var finalurl = '';

    function fun1(){

        for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
          str = "http://" + arr[i]  + "/images/";
          finalurl = str + "image-l.gif"  + "?id=" + (new Date()).getTime();
          ping(finalurl);
          textt += results[i] + " ";     
          $(‘#ping’).html(textt);

        }
    }


var ping = function(finalurl) {

    var l = 0;

    t.push((new Date()).getTime());
    if(t.length > n) {
        p=t[2]-t[1];
       results.push(p);
    }
    else {
      var img = new Image;
      $(img).load(function() {
        ping();
      }).attr('src', finalurl);      
    }
}
```

//small part of html:

```
<h2><a href="#" onclick="fun1();">run</a></h2>
  <h1 id=“ping”> </h1>
```

Comment: can you show expected output and actual output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This generates three urls (the `length` of `arr`) but only attempts to show two (the value of `n`). The urls are different each time, but you are limiting them in `ping` so the new ones are not used.

Try setting `n` to higher number, you will see it will load more images each click - as it currently stands it tries to load more in a single click (3) than it allows (2).

Note: even if those urls are different, the images may be the same, this happens if the server ignores the `id` parameter... which probably does as it requires additional configuration for the server to handle requests to a ".gif" resource (which is not a known servcer side scripting language) - by default the server will just return the resource `image-l.gif`.

By the way: At `$(‘#ping’)` those are the wrong quotes. Also `textt` is not defined - I did define it as `var textt = '';` for my tests.